# How to parse UTF-8 Chinese string

Tags: c++, boost, utf-8, boost-spirit

I am trying to parse a `std::string` that might contain Chinese characters. For example for a string contains

```
哈囉hi你好hello
```

I want to separate them into 6 strings:`哈`, `囉`, `hi`, `你`, `好`, `hello`. Right now the string is obtained by using `getline()` from a text file. Referencing this post [How to use boost::spirit to parse UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679669/how-to-use-boostspirit-to-parse-utf-8), here's my current code:

```
#include <boost/regex/pending/unicode_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;
using namespace std::string_literals; 

int main()
{
    string str = u8"哈囉hi你好hello"; //actually got from getline()
    auto &&utf8_text = str;

    u8_to_u32_iterator<const char*>
        tbegin(begin(utf8_text)), tend(end(utf8_text));

    vector<uint32_t> result;
    spirit::qi::parse(tbegin, tend, *spirit::standard_wide::char_, result);
    for(auto &&code_point : result) {
        cout << code_point << ";";
    }
}
```

But got the error: call to 'begin' and 'end' is ambiguous. 
It works when I directly declare `auto &&utf8_text = u8"哈囉hi你好hello"`, but I cannot write in this way because the content of string is determined by `getline()`.

I also tried this:

```
auto str = u8"你好，世界！";
auto &&utf8_text = str;
```

but still got error: no matching function for call to 'begin' and 'end'.

Comment: Have you tried `u8_to_u32_iterator<std::string::iterator>`? There is no guarantee `begin()` and `end()` return pointers.

Comment: Thank you. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

`auto` with string literals results in a char pointer. If you want `std::string`, you have to write it out.