# Boost spirit semantic actions on qi::rule

Tags: boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I've been reading up on semantic actions and I have a rule that looks like this:

```
  property_rule %=
    identifier_rule % ','
    >> lit(L":")
    >> type_specification_rule
    >> -(lit(L":=") >> +(alnum - ';'))
    >> lit(L";");
```

The `property_rule` is defined as

```
qi::rule<Iterator, property(), space_type> property_rule;
```

Now, I also want to support operator `≡` so what I want is to change the rule to something like

```
...
>> -(( lit(L":=") || lit(L"≡")[SEMANTIC_ACTION_HERE]) >> +(alnum - ';'))
...
```

In the semantic action, I want to change the `property` that is being parsed, specifically setting its field `is_constant` to `true`. The property is Fusion-adapted. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

I would - as ever - avoid the semantic action *([Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil) )*.

I'd simply synthesize the value for `is_constant` on both branches of the alternative:

```
>> -(( lit(L":=") || lit(L"≡")[SEMANTIC_ACTION_HERE]) >> +(alnum - ';'))
```

would become instead:

```
>> -(
        (L":=" >> attr(false) | L"≡" >> ::attr(true)) >> +(alnum - ';')
    )
```

Notes:

1. the `lit` is implied
2. you probably do not want `||` parser operator
3. this assumes that the `is_constant` field is adapted in the fusion sequence

Comment: Umm, you are making the assumption that when the fusion sequence is adapted, the `bool is_constant` is present in the order such that it comes *before* the name of the variable. It doesn't. It comes after. As a consequence, `attr(false)` would try to assign a `bool` to a `wstring`. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Yeah. Fix the order in the rule. Adapt in a more useful order. Use a named fusion view :) (Also, I had no way to even guess about the presence or absence of "variables" in the grammar, either before or after the operator-like symbol. I just noted that since you felt comfortable just mentioning "fusion adapted", I was comfortable just mentioning I was relying on that).

Comment: I've changed fusion order but now the `+(alnum - ';')` part doesn't parse into its requisite `wstring`, any idea why that could be?

Comment: No, because you're not showing a SSCCE (out on a limb, try [`qi::as_wstring`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/as.html))

Comment: (In case you want to look at a Phoenix - not auto-propagate - approach, see e.g. the [PS. section here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17347961/85371))